# Android studio User registration data NOT get inserted to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code above is to insert user registration data into the firebase database. but when I build the app and try to insert some demo data into the database to perform a user registration none of them is being inserted to the firebase. can anyone check my code and find out anything that I have done wrong?

```
public class CreateProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etName,etBio,etProfession,etEmail,etWeb;
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Uri imageUri;
    UploadTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() ;
    DocumentReference documentReference;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE=1;
    All_User_Member member;
    String currentUserId;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

        member = new All_User_Member();
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_cp);
        etBio = findViewById(R.id.et_bio_cp);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email_cp);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.et_name_cp);
        etProfession = findViewById(R.id.et_profession_cp);
        etWeb = findViewById(R.id.et_web_cp);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_cp);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_cp);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        currentUserId = user.getUid();

        //reference
        documentReference = db.collection("user").document(currentUserId);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Profile images");
        databaseReference = database.getReference("All users");

        //button click
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadData();
            }
        });


        //ProfileImageSelect
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select image"),PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });


    }

    //LoadingProfileImage


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {

            if (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE || resultCode== RESULT_OK || data != null || data.getData() !=null){
                imageUri = data.getData();

                Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Error"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }

    private String getFileExt(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType((contentResolver.getType(uri)));
    }



    private void uploadData() {

        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String bio = etBio.getText().toString();
        String web = etWeb.getText().toString();
        String prof = etProfession.getText().toString();
        String mail = etEmail.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(bio) || TextUtils.isEmpty(web) || TextUtils.isEmpty(prof) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(mail) || imageUri != null){

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+getFileExt(imageUri));
            uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageUri);

            Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return reference.getDownloadUrl();

                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {


                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();


                        Map<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
                        profile.put("name", name);
                        profile.put("prof", prof);
                        profile.put("url", downloadUri.toString());
                        profile.put("bio", bio);
                        profile.put("mail", mail);
                        profile.put("web", web);
                        profile.put("privacy", "Public");

                        member.setName(name);
                        member.setProf(prof);
                        member.setUid(currentUserId);
                        member.setUrl(downloadUri.toString());

                        databaseReference.child(currentUserId).setValue(member);

                        documentReference.set(profile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Profile Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(CreateProfile.this,Fragment1.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                },2000);

                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            });

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors getting in the android studio:

[image]

Comment: There are no errors because you aren't checking that. Have you tried to attach a failure listener to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: no brh! I'm still new to android development. I cant find where I have mistaken or gone wrong.

Comment: You've shared quite a bit of code in your question, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. I recommend setting breakpoints in the code, running it in a debugger, and then stepping through it line by line, checking the variables at each step. If you do that, which line is the *first* that doesn't do what you expect it to do?